# Array sorting: Alphabetical and Numerically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I want a webpage that has a text box. There are two buttons underneath the text box that says "Sort Alphabetically" and "Sort numerically." I want it so that whatever the user types in the box, it sorts. If the user types in numbers and letters, it will cancel the sorting and an alert will pop up saying "Cannot be letters and numbers." When the "Sort Alphabetically" button is clicked, the JavaScript code will activate and sort the words alphabetically. Same goes with the "Sort Numerically" button. I can't seem to get the words/numbers to sort.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sorter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sorter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Words/Numbers to Be Sorted:<input type="text" id="textbox" size="35"/>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="sortAbc()">Sort Alphabetically</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sortNumber()">Sort Numerically</button>
<br/>
<h1>Each number/word shall be separated by a space.</h1>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sortAbc() {
var captureText = document.getElementById('textbox');
captureText.sort();
//Help! How to make alert pop up when numbers and letters are typed?
}

function sortNumber() {
var captureNumb = document.getElementByid('textbox');
captureNumb.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
//Same problem here! How to make alert pop up when numbers and letters are typed?
}
```

Comment: Where is your approach? Where is your jQuery anyway? You have to use the `onChange` event from the text input box...

Comment: Hire a developer or do due diligence and make a decent attempt at it before you ask others to do your work.

Comment: I think it's very complex to sort the field in which you are typing. You can maybe wait for some seconds or for leaving focus to this field and than sort it. If you want to sort it while typing then you shall get the content (string) and divide it be whitespaces. The resulting array you can sort. Then back to string and in the textbox. But where you want to set the position of the cursor while sorting...?

Comment: @algorhythm It appears that yolotheone is asking for the check to happen in the sorting functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here a complet live sample.

- check for number or words using regular expression (`.match`)
- use the array function `sort`

```js
function sortAbc() {
   var captureText = document.getElementById('textbox');
   if (captureText.value.match(/(?:^| )[\d]+(?: |$)/)) {
     alert("no digits");
     return;
   }
   var words = captureText.value.split(" ");
   captureText.value = words.sort().join(" ");
}

function sortNumber() {
   var captureNumb = document.getElementById('textbox');
   if (captureNumb.value.match(/[^\s\d]/)) {
     alert("no letters");
     return;
   }
   var numbers = captureNumb.value.split(" ");
   captureNumb.value = numbers.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b }).join(" ");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Sorter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sorter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Words/Numbers to Be Sorted:<input type="text" id="textbox" size="35"/>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="sortAbc()">Sort Alphabetically</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sortNumber()">Sort Numerically</button>
<br/>
<h1>Each number/word shall be separated by a space.</h1>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since sport() returns the array you can just do: split("").sort(comparator).join("") which is more elegant imho.